# Why use Coded Variables in Experimental Design?

Tags: experiment-design, simulation

Full-disclosure, I'm not sure if this ENTIRELY on-topic.

Often times, most texts will suggest that we code our variables. i.e. If we move from 345 to 350 to 355, we code our variables as -1, 0, and 1. So, let's say we are dealing with a massive data set or perhaps simulating a large data set (which might of interest in percolation theory for example). Each parameter is varied nine times giving coded variables from -4 to 4. Overall, we have $9^3$ different variations times however many replicates are used. Clearly, this is a pretty big number. We might use our response data to perform a regression analysis based on this simulated data.

So, I'm wondering if there is really a purpose to using coded variables. Are they more computationally efficient? Wouldn't putting in a code the method by which we determine how each variable is coded negate any added efficiency? Basically, why use coded variables?

Comment: You talk of "use" and "computationally efficient" but it's not quite clear what you mean. Are you talking about data to be used in regression analysis or classification? Somewhere where you're using numeric optimization? Something else?

Comment: Edited. Doing some kind of regression analysis. I've seen it a lot when finding steepest incline on a response surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you centre the variables then the estimated intercept will be in the centre of the design space. This may well make it easier to interpret although of course you can always use the raw variables and back-calculate the value for anywhere.

In the Good Old Days when computer numerical analysis was not so well developed we often found that centering our predictors avoided numerical problems but these days that should not be a consideration. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/longley.html for an example of a famous dataset which used to be used to demonstrate the issues.